# html5 localstorage contacts managment web

Tags: html, contacts

i have to make Contacts management website using html5 local-storage please tell me is that possible in local-storage ? and how and which api to use? if need? please guide me some initial coding step towards it.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to store the  data in local storage .But, you need to think in terms of data size because different web browsers have different storage restrictions.

local storage stores items in key-value pairs and values are in string formats and you need to convert the object to string by JSON.stringify and convert back to object by JSON.parse(string).

```
localStorage.test="hello"; // here test is key and value is "hello".

var CustomObject={};

localStorage.object=JSON.stringify(CustomObject); store custom object 

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.object)); //retrieve object and display
```

in the console.

Most browsers store around 5 mb of data .so ,check the browser support and restrctions.

You can also use sqllite storage to  build the html5 application but there is limited  support on this by most of the  browsers.

see this website for more info  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage